# Getting a proper select query in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, string, oracle, where-clause

I have a requirement where I need to show results based on an input string in a report fetching from db.

It has **firstname, lastname and dob** input fields.

Example: If I query with the firstname in the firstname box,and keep the other 2 empty, I should get all results with that first name and show all the 3 fields in a separate table in the report (**considering null values in columns too**) .

I have earlier written this query -

```
select * 
from Emp_table 
where f_fname like v_fname and f_lname like v_lname and f_dob like v_dob
```

Here v_fname is -

v_fname := case when in_fname is null then '%' else in_fname end;

(in_fname - value of the input query)

But in this case if any column has null (fname,lname or dob) its not picked up by the query.

Please suggest a consolidated query which will take up all 3 values - **'%', null or the input value**.

Sample -

[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGpKP.jpg)

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55bW3.png)

The empty values given in the sample output are fetched from db and are null.

Comment: Sample data and expected result along with table structure in text format would be helpful

Comment: Like @Sujitmohanty30 suggested, kindly provide the sample inputs and output. Explain how get expected output from your inputs. Then you will get the code to arrive at your expected result.

Comment: Added the sample input and output

Answer (score 1):

You can be explicit about `null` parameter values:

```
select * 
from emp_table 
where 
        (v_fname is null or f_fname like v_fname)
    and (v_lname is null or f_lname like v_lname)
    and (v_dob   is null or f_dob   like v_dob)
```

If a parameter is given a `null` value, any value is accepted (including `null`s). If a parameter's value is `'%'`, then anything but `null` values is allowed. Any other value is taken as a literal filter.

Beware, however, that if the parameter has embedded percent sign, they will be interpreted as wildcard characters. This might, or might not be what you want.

Comment: If I am giving f_lname as an input query its fetching records with f_lname as well as those records where f_lname and f_fname and f_dob all are null, or f_fname, f_lname are null etc..

Comment: @ananya0208: As GMB has said: Just be explicit about null values. If you want another rule then GMB has shown, then apply that other rule. *Maybe* you want `(f_fname like v_fname or (v_fname is null and f_fname is null)) and ...`.

Comment: I have given the sample input and output, just need to fetch results like that - by giving an input name, and results that are pulled up may contain null/non null values for other columns.

Comment: @ananya0208: Both GMB's and my `WHERE` clause would select the sample rows you are showing. Maybe you need to show a better example (and as text, not as images please), showing not only paramters and result but also the table data. And anyway, what keeps you from modifying our `WHERE` clauses so they match the rules you have in mind? Do you understand our `WHERE` clauses? Or is there something about them you don't understand?